# Root of a function involving an integral

Tags: integration, roots, problem-solving

I need to dynamically solve an equation for a function $g(t)$ which is multiplied by another expression involving an integral of $g(t)$.

Specifically, I have
\begin{align} \tag{1} 
\sigma^{target}(t) = g(t) \sigma^{input} \sqrt{\frac{1}{T_i} \int_{0}^{T_i} g^2(s) ds} 
\end{align}

I know $\sigma_{target}$ and  $\sigma_{input}$. Furthermore, 
$$ g(t) = 
\begin{cases}
  1 & 0 \leq t \leq T_{i-1} \leq T_i \\
? &  T_{i-1}\leq t \leq T_{i}
\end{cases}
$$

Without the part involving the integral, this would be straightforward and I'd use a iterative/bootstrapper to solve for g(t) for $t \in [0, T_i]$ but the integral complicates this task as I'd need $g(t)$ to determine that integral.

I want to find some empirical estimate of g(t) for some grid $t \in (t_0, ..., t_n = T_i)$

I was suggested to first give a guess of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{T_i} \int_{0}^{T_i} g^2(s) ds}$, then solve for $g(t)$ and iteratively updated my guess until I arrive at the root of equation $(1)$.